# Lock out all users from controller using Authorize attribute

Tags: asp.net-mvc, authorization

I want to use the Authorize attribute in MVC to lock out ALL users in an application.

I need this because I am putting together a live style guide demo in our website project that other devs can use while they're developing pages. However, I obviously don't want the controller to be accessible to anybody in production.

So, I was hoping I could do something like this:

```
[Authorize(Roles="<insert some magic string here to lock out all users>")]
public class StyleGuideController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

Devs could then uncomment that attribute when they wanted to see the style guide (and never check in that change).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

why not try something like this instead:

```
#if DEBUG
public class StyleGuideController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }
}
#endif
```

no need to change code around each time (fewer accidental check-ins where a developer left it in).  as long as the developer is running in debug mode, he'll have access to that controller.  in release mode, anyone else will get 404 error